# Why use HTML.ActionLink instead of a Common anchor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

The sentence bellow generate a HTML anchor pointing to an action in a ASP.net MVC Controller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "Action", "Controller")
```

But the code bellow does the same thing:

```
<A href="~\Controller\Action">Text</a>
```

The Second option seems better to me, because is less complex, and It would allow event to put complex HTML elements inside.

So is there a reason I should use the first over the second?

Comment: The `ActionLink()` method will always generate the correct url based on its arguments (and if you want html elements inside your `<a>`, then its typical to use `<a href="Url.Action(...)"` to generate the url)

Comment: And in wich situation would the Second option not generate a correct URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Action","Controller")">Text or Inner html</a>
```

This code allows you to put HTML inside.

Code like this: "~\Controller\Action" may cause problem if you use custom routing. 
For Example you want to use name of Action before Controller in URL.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion first one looks better, because you can add your route parameters and htmlAttributes in specific fields. Easy to read. For example

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "Action", "Controller", new { id = item.ID }, new htmlAttributes {})
```